# Windows10 bypassed my bogus proxy, or did it?

Tags: virtualbox, malware

I'd like to know what could I have done to let Windows bypass a fake proxy setting.

I want to keep Windows 10 host offline while the guest machine would be able to use the internet. I just need 10 for CG animation work.

A Superuser(I forget the username) suggested to add a fake proxy address to Windows 10 and that would keep it from connecting. I would run Virtualbox connecting to the net via a Bridged Adapter. It works great, it did for 6 months.

Last Monday it told me when I woke it from sleep that I needed to restart for updates to apply. What?

Seems impossible that Windows 10 would suddenly know how to get around my bogus proxy to start updating by itself.

Retracing my steps that weekend I was using 10 to copy a HDD from my laptop to an SSD, to do so I installed software to shrink and clone a drive and I suspect that maybe I downloaded malware that figured out how to bypass my proxy and Windows suddenly found its way to connecting to the internet as well?

It's my best guess, I can't see how else it could have suddenly wised up.

Comment: Well I discovered that eventually Windows update finds a way through even when you say you use a proxy. The updates just take forever to download but eventually they do.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely solution to prevent internet activity form the host machine is to disable IPv4 and IPv6 for the host machine. Once this is done there should be a red X on the connected icon in the icon tray. I don't think it will be able to download updates once they are disabled.

Path to disable IPv4 and IPv6:

Control panel >Network and Sharing Center >Change Adapter Settings
Right click on the Ethernet icon.
Choose Properties
Uncheck IPv4 and IPv6
Hit OK
Disabled

This does not affect the virtual machines as they use Virtualbox's own network connection who have their own adapter configurations when using a Bridged Adapter.